# Searching throught 2 tables and check if cars are taken on the searched dates

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Okay so im quiet new to coding and im trying to do a car rental system and im stuck at the main page which has the search button which is a simple date picker , on the other side i have a database which contains current reservations made from other clients on X cars with X start date and X end date. Now here's the tricky part . I collected the search Start Date & Return date from inputed fields and also collected the Start & end date from Reservations database, i compared them both  to check if inputed dates are bigger / smaller or equal to the Reservations one so i skip it because the client is looking for a car in the inputed search dates and if the dates are equal or inbetween we skip this car.

Now , lets say i think i have correctly checked the dates , on the reservations table i save the cars ID which is selected car and what i want to do is to show the details of available cars on the inputed dates , now the thing is that Reservations and Cars are 2 different tables also i dont know how to compare or check if selected car is on cars list and is it taken on all dates inputed or is it free . this is the part that im currently stuck .

Overall what i want to do if i wasnt clear enought.

Search Start / Return date - Show cars that are available on inputed dates - if they are not , dont show.

Here's My Code

```
<!--Car Cover-->
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $startDate = $_POST['pickupDate'];
    $returnDate = $_POST['returnDate'];

    $startDate = new DateTime($startDate);
    $returnDate = new DateTime($returnDate);
    $startDate = $startDate->format("m-d");
    $returnDate = $returnDate->format("m-d");
    if(empty($startDate))
    {
      $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "Pickup Date can't be empty";
      TakeTo("index");
    }
    elseif(empty($returnDate))
    {
      $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "Return Date can't be empty";
      TakeTo("index");
    }
    elseif($startDate == $returnDate)
    {
      $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "Cars can only be rented for 1 or more days";
      TakeTo("index");
    }
    elseif($returnDate <= $startDate)
    {
      $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "Return date cannot be before Pickup Date";
      TakeTo("index");
    }
    echo "Search Start Date : $startDate - Search End Date : $returnDate <br>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservations";
    $stmt = $con->query($sql);

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM cars";
    $stmt2 = $con->query($sql2);
    while($info = $stmt->fetch())
    {
      $Start = new DateTime($info['start_date']);
      $End = new DateTime($info['end_date']);
      $Start = $Start->format("m-d");
      $End = $End->format("m-d");
      $selectedCar = $info['selected_car'];
      while($carInfo = $stmt2->fetch())
      {
      
      if($carID == $selectedCar)
      {
        continue;
      }
        $carID = $carInfo['id'];
      $carName = $carInfo['car_name'];
      $product_year = $carInfo['production_year'];
      $engine = $carInfo['engine'];
     // print( "Start is :$Start - End is :$End - StartDate is :$startDate - Return Date is :$returnDate<br>");

      echo "Car Name : $carName - product_year : $product_year - engine : $engine  - Start Date : $Start - End : $End  - Car ID : $carID<br>";
      }
      if($Start == $startDate || $End == $returnDate ||$startDate >= $Start && $startDate <= $End || $startDate <= $Start && $startDate <= $End)
      {
        continue;
      }
      
      
    }

  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are there no times, just dates?  Can a car be picked up on the date it is returned or only on the next day?

Comment: You talk about showing a list of cars that are available; that part makes sense.  But your actual code seems designed to list reservations, not available cars.  Is that part just wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ysth okay so i have 2 tables , one is reservations and other one is the cars , so my main idea was to get the dates from reservations table because thats where you can check if the dates inputed by client are the matching with the one with reservations so you skip these dates . And the cars part is where i was stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a car can only be picked up on the day after its return, you want:

```
select c.id,c.car_name,c.production_year,c.engine
from cars c
left join reservations r on
    r.selected_car=c.id and
    greatest(r.start_date,?) <= least(r.end_date,?)
where r.selected_car is null
```

(passing your desired start date and end date, as YYYY-MM-DD).

Note that you cannot detect overlap of two time ranges just by comparing end and start separately; you will miss cases where one range is entirely within the other.

The left join looks for reservations for each car that would make it unavailable; the where condition excludes cars where there is such a reservation.

Comment: the dates check you provided will skip this 

Example , one car is taken from 01-26 till 01 - 28 and if i search from 01 - 27 till 02-03 , the car will show up as available

Comment: @Dit works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/ys32nttL  the car is not available when looking for 1/27-2/3 and available when looking for 1/29-2/3